# How to access tomcat page when using tomcat maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, tomcat7

I have created a SOAP service and using tomcat maven plugin for deploying in tomcat server.

```html
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am able to start application and able to get wsdl also when using this end point - http://localhost:8080/soapapptest

[image]

everything is working, but when I used this endpoint http://localhost:8080 for getting tomcat home page then I got below page.

[image]

how I will get the tomcat home page where I can see my deployed war?

After starting application I am getting following logs

[image]

Comment: Did you deploy an app, or anything at all, to the ROOT context? It usually ships with one that handles the home page, but if you don't deploy it, this would happen.

Comment: yes I  have deployed the war file, added detail for same

Comment: Not one named ROOT.war, so the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The home page is an application that gets deployed to the "ROOT" context. You'll find it in the downloadable Tomcat .tar.gz and .zip files. Unless your `pom.xml` deploys an application as ROOT, you are supposed to get a 404 response for `/`.